# Take off the sentence "text-content" in QR code

Tags: qr-code

I tried to make a QR code first with an online website and then with javascript but each time, when I read the QR code made by theses methods, before my text, I have "text-content" who is written.
How to write without this sentence because I saw a QR code from someone without it.

Can you help me ?

Thanks .

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible code example.

Comment: Here is picture of the subject: https://ibb.co/kJbGt7B

Comment: "Text content: " is not contained in the QR code. It's your app adding it. Use a different app.

Comment: Thanks "codo", I thought that it was my fault but it was actually the app.  !